# iOS Swift Couchbase Lite Primary Key and Class Configuration

Tags: ios, swift, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I was going through couchbase-lite to use it in my next iOS app. I have created a model named Surah for now. Definitely, I will have more model classes later.

Basically I have four questions here.

- How do I add _id as my primary key in couchbase-lite?
- As I will be having more classes how will I handle those? As I am creating
  MutableDocument, How will that differentiate each my classes?
- As I can see I have to iterate through each of my items to batch insert, won't that become slow for the large datasets?
- How do i convert results from a query with large data to a array of Model Class. (in this case of array of Surah)

  class Surah: Decodable {

  ```
  enum Keys: String, CodingKey {
      case _id
      case index
      case englishName
      case englishMeaning
      case name
      case place
      case count
  }

  var _id = ""
  var index = 1
  var page = 1
  var numberOfAyahs = 1
  var englishName = ""
  var englishMeaning = ""
  var name = ""
  var place = ""
  var isFavorite = false

  var dictionary: [String: Any] {
      return ["_id": _id, "index": index, "page": page]
  }

  required init() {}

  required init(_id: String, index: Int, name: String, englishName: String, englishMeaning: String, place: String, count: Int) {
      self._id = _id
      self.index = index
      self.name = name
      self.englishName = englishName
      self.englishMeaning = englishMeaning
      self.place = place
      self.numberOfAyahs = count
  }


  required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Keys.self) // defining our (keyed) container
      let _id: String = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: ._id)
      let index: Int = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .index)
      let name: String = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
      let englishName: String = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .englishName)
      let englishMeaning: String = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .englishMeaning)
      let place: String = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .place)
      let count: Int = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .count)
      self.init(_id: _id, index: index, name: name, englishName: englishName, englishMeaning: englishMeaning, place: place, count: count)
  }}
  ```

Code for Database Queries

```
let surahs = try JSONDecoder().decode([Surah].self, from: data!)

                                        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                                            //background code
                                            do {
                                                if let db = App.shared.database {
                                                    try db.inBatch {
                                                        for item in surahs {
                                                            let doc = MutableDocument(data: item.dictionary)
                                                            doc.setString("users", forKey: "type")
                                                            doc.setValue(Keys._id, forKey: item._id)
//                                                            doc.setValue(Keys.englishName, forKey: item.englishName)
                                                            try db.saveDocument(doc)

                                                            let index = IndexBuilder.valueIndex(items:
                                                                ValueIndexItem.expression(Expression.property("_id")), ValueIndexItem.expression(Expression.property("type")))
                                                            try db.createIndex(index, withName: "TypeNameIndex")
                                                            print("saved user document \(doc.string(forKey: "englishName"))")
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            } catch let error {
                                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                    seal.reject(error)
                                                }
                                            }
                                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                seal.fulfill(surahs)
                                            }
                                        }
```

Comment: Okay got the primary key part. I added the primary key in this way...
let doc = MutableDocument(id: item._id, data: item.dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

1. Not sure what you mean by "primary key".  You can always find a doc
   by its id.  The name of the field that contains it is `Meta.id`. 
   The field's value is `mutableDoc.getId()`.  As you've noticed, you
   can also explicitly set the id at creation
2. Couchbase doesn't store classes, it stores JSON documents.  If you
   have documents of different types (different internal structures,
   analogous to different SQL tables), give them a type field and use
   it in your query
3. Use `Database.inBatch()`
4. The same way you would convert any JSON document to a corresponding
   class: gson, Jackson, Moshi, etc